# Composer ignore folders on package require

Tags: directory, composer-php

I want to use a package with composer require but I don't want it to load all the folders. I know that I should fork this package on github and make my changes, but I want to easily update the package when need, and copy/pasting folders isn't the best option.

So, I was thinking, is it possible to somehow on my forked repository on `composer.json` file, tell that I don't want to load `Eloquent` and `Console` folders from the `illuminate/database` package?

reference: https://github.com/illuminate/database

Comment: Why? Not wanting to use code that's considered necessary doesn't explain why you cannot spare that small amount of hard drive space.

Comment: I just want to use QueryBuilder, in a small website for a client that has a really smal hosting plan. Thats not much in terms of size, but theres no need to use this unecessary folders

Comment: Then write a deployment script that runs `composer install` locally, deletes everything you don't need, and then SFTP it to the clients' webhost. That way you'll gain way more potential bytes than by fiddling with only one package. Other things to do during this script: Compress Javascript, optimize/compress images and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there is no way to exclude these folders from Composer.

And I will never understand why some people are still hunting for the last 2 bytes of disk space. Disk space is really cheap nowadays.
And for example you would never go and delete some single functions that you don't use from a package or do you?

In almost any package/framework I use, there are some things I don't use but it would never come into my mind to remove them unless I'm a NASA guy sending my code to Pluto or something.

**My advice:** Keep these files unless there is a really big need to have them removed.

If you need to remove them you could write a script and run it at a `post-package-update` event.

Here is how you define a script event in your `composer.json`:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": "MyVendor\\MyClass::postUpdate",
        "post-package-install": [
            "MyVendor\\MyClass::postPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "MyVendor\\MyClass::warmCache",
            "phpunit -c app/"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd" : [
            "php -r \"copy('config/local-example.php', 'config/local.php');\""
        ]
    }
}
```

And an example for the `MyVendor\MyClass` class:

```php
<?php

namespace MyVendor;

use Composer\Script\Event;
use Composer\Installer\PackageEvent;

class MyClass
{
    public static function postUpdate(Event $event)
    {
        $composer = $event->getComposer();
        // do stuff
    }

    public static function postPackageInstall(PackageEvent $event)
    {
        $installedPackage = $event->getOperation()->getPackage();
        // do stuff
    }

    public static function warmCache(Event $event)
    {
        // make cache toasty
    }
}
```

For more on how to use scripts see the [official composer documentation - scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#defining-scripts).

Comment: The use case isn't so much saving disk space as it is about keeping things clean and not having unnecessarily files in places they don't need to be. That shouldn't be controversial....

Comment: @siride So do you throw out the functions/procedures of a framework that you never use just to keep it clean? I mean he is basically trying to do exactly that if he tries to remove files that are part of a package. • If I include a package, then I include the whole package and not parts of it. At least that is what every coder that will need to work on that project in the future would expect if he sees a package included. • Even if I only use one single function of a package that has 100 functions, I will need to include the whole package. I think that's just how the idea of packages works.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It was always common to exclude things not directly related to running a program/project. I don't need tests and readmes in my production code. Of course I will take the time to exclude those from the final "build", but why should I have to do that? Using your logic, there shouldn't also be dev dependencies. Indeed, why not just include all packages available in the repository since disk space is cheap and it doesn't matter?

Comment: @siride Of course I would not include a package that I don't use at all. But if `composer.json` says package XY is required then it need to be possible to assume that the full package is included and not that someone removed parts of it after it was included (which would drive every coder nuts if he would try to use one of the removed functions later). I consider this just a very bad practice. Also if you remove parts of a package this is also untested and not considered stable anymore.

Comment: If you need a light weight package of an existing package the best way in my opinion would be to fork it, throw out what you don't need, test it, declare it as stable and include the fork in your desired project. This way every coder immediately sees that it is not the full (original) package and this way it is tested, that it is working without the thrown out functions.